# Is this SASS code, that uses the mixin function, too verbose?

Tags: sass

I feel that the code for this **mixin** is too verbose, Please help.
Please feel free to pass any recommendations in regards to mixins.

```
  @mixin bold { font-weight: bold; }

  @mixin normal { font-weight: normal; }

  @mixin font($bold, $normal) {
    @if ($bold) {
      @include bold

    } @else {
      font-weight: normal;
    }
  }

  h1 { @include font(false, false) }
  h2 { @include font(true, true) }
```

Comment: Why are you writing a mixin for this? @mozaick

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify it:

```
$bold: 700;
$normal: 400;

h1 {
    font-weight: $bold;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: $normal;
}
```